# PowerBI Datetime filter acts like every other filter?

Tags: datetime, filter, powerbi

I'm brand new to Power BI and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I would expect a "date/time" field would have special options for filtering.  However, the filter actually lists a dropdown of all values ("2015-09-24 12:00:01", "2015-09-24 12:00:02", "2015-09-24 12:00:03", etc).

How can I filter by "last year" or "last 7 days"?  Am I missing something simple?

I have tried in the web interface and Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the field's data type to Date/Time. If you're seeing strings, the most common issue is that in the query the field is defined as type "any", which gets interpreted as a string.  So just go to the query window, change the data type for the affected columns, and see what happens.  One little hint, is that usually after you use a function or transform (especially Add Column!) the resulting column will have the "any" data type.  So double check and set the data type you really want.